# JavaFX Generalize GridPane Column Constraints

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Is there any way of apply a column constraint to all my GridPanes columns.
I have various GridPane controls and I would like them to share the following column constraint:

```
<ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="388.0" minWidth="74.0" prefWidth="74.0" />
```

Could it be done using css?

**Edit**

I ended up doing something like this. But it does not work (my columns width get resized below 74), any clue ?

```
public static void resizeColumns(Pane parent){
        for (Node component : parent.getChildren()) {
            if (component instanceof GridPane) {
                GridPane gridPane = (GridPane) component;
                ObservableList<ColumnConstraints> columnConstraints = gridPane.getColumnConstraints();
                for (ColumnConstraints column : columnConstraints) {
                    column.setMinWidth(74.0);
                }
        } else if (component instanceof Pane) {
            resizeColumns((Pane) component);
        } else if (component instanceof ScrollPane) {
            resizeColumns((Pane) ((ScrollPane) component).getContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your java controller code, loop through the columns and set whatever values you need.

Comment: How can I loop over the controls of the scene ? I tried with getChildrenUnmodifiable() but it returns only the first level of children

Comment: Isn't this OK?  If you have other containers in the grid pane then these containers should handle their own layout in their own way.  For example, a VBox should act like a VBox even in the GridPane.